# calculating completed task ratio

Tags: sql

I've a table with NAMES and STATUS with C(completed) and N(not completed) status. I want check how many tasks are not completed for each name. I tried the following code and it is returning all '0' values:

select name, (select count(status) from alteon where status= 'n') / (select count(status) from alteon) from alteon group by name;

I'm expecting the result as **not completed / total assigned** where total assigned = complete+not completed.

as mentioned earlier, I'm getting value as '0' beside each employee name.

Comment: Please give your tables and your need clearly. Try to explain with a sqlfiddle

Comment: Hi sulthan, please check this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223db/1

Comment: I am looking back your sqlfiddle, and working on it.

Comment: thank you sultan, waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query which gives the result as you explained above.

```
 select count(status)as Total_assigned,
 sum(IF(status='n', 1, 0)) as Not_completed,name
 from alteon group by name ;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223db/33)

Comment: Thank you rajesh, I'm expecting the result as not completed / total assigned where total assigned = complete + not completed, grouped by name.  Your query displayed the count as per n,c with names

Comment: @user3454315 : Check the edited answer above for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query does what you want:

```
select name,
       sum(case when status = 'n' then 1 else 0 end) as n_status,
       avg(case when status = 'n' then 1.0 else 0 end) as n_status_ratio
from alteon;
```

Comment: excellent Gordon Linoff it worked buy, I want % of the ratio. i.e Alex status ration is 0.25, I want it as 25%

Comment: @user3454315 . . . Alas, formatting numbers varies by the database and you haven't tagged your question with the database.

Comment: I'm getting an error Gordon, please check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f20d8/7

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multiple select statements. Use CASE to count the incomplete tasks.

```
select name, count(case when status = 'n' then 1 else null end)/count(status)
  from alteon
group by name;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1790b/1).

Comment: excellent it worked but, I want % of the ratio. i.e Alex status ration is 0.25, I want it to display status as 25%. Thanks for your time

Comment: then just multiply it by hundred.